# How to reset the for loop with out loosing the info entered for the previous "batter"?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, reset

My problem is when the console prints the results; the program seems to be adding all of the results and I can't seem to figure out how to reset each one with out loosing it. **I'm pretty sure the problem lies on the for loop but I still have no idea on how to fix it.**

Here is the full code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class BattingAverageApp
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double successfulRuns = 0;
    double totalBases = 0;
    int atbatt = 0;
    String message = " ";

    AtBat bat = new AtBat();

    System.out.print("Number of batters:    ");
    int batters = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    bat.setPlayers(batters);

    int[] atbat = new int[batters];
    double[][] calculate = new double[batters][2];

    outerLoop:
    for(int a = 0; a < batters; a++)
    {
    atbat[a] = Validator.getInt(sc, "Enter the number of times at bat for player "
        + (a+1) + ":    ", 0, 11);
    System.out.println();

    atbatt = atbat[a];

    double[] results = new double[atbatt];

    System.out.println("0 = out, 1 = single, 2 = double, 3 = triple, 4 = home run");

        for(int i = 0; i < atbatt; i++)
        {
            results[i] = 0;

            results[i] = Validator.getInt(sc, "Results for at-bat " + i + ":    ", -1, 5);
            bat.setResult(results[i]);

            if (results[i] > 0)
            successfulRuns++;
            totalBases += results[i];
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for(int a = 0; a < batters; a++)
    {
    calculate[a][0] = successfulRuns / (double)atbatt;
    calculate[a][1] = totalBases / (double)atbatt;

    NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    number.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);

    message = "Batting average: " + number.format(calculate[a][0]) + "\t"
        + "Slugging percent: " + number.format(calculate[a][1]);

    System.out.println(message);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Here is what the **console prints out**, when I select one player:

```
 Number of batters:      1

 Enter the number of times at bat for player 1:  3

 0 = out, 1 = single, 2 = double, 3 = triple, 4 = home run
 Results for at-bat 0:   0
 Results for at-bat 1:   4
 Results for at-bat 2:   0

 Batting average: 0.333  Slugging percent: 1.333

 Press any key to continue . . .
```

And here is what it prints out when I select more than one player:

```
Number of batters:      2

Enter the number of times at bat for player 1:  3

0 = out, 1 = single, 2 = double, 3 = triple, 4 = home run
Results for at-bat 0:   0
Results for at-bat 1:   4
Results for at-bat 2:   0

Enter the number of times at bat for player 2:  2

0 = out, 1 = single, 2 = double, 3 = triple, 4 = home run
Results for at-bat 0:   0
Results for at-bat 1:   1

Batting average: 1.000  Slugging percent: 2.500
Batting average: 1.000  Slugging percent: 2.500

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Are you getting any exceptions? Also, what do you mean by 'player'?

Comment: can u make clear by viewing us the difference between the 2 cases (select 1 batter and select more).

Comment: I will post the rest of the code when I get home.

Comment: @Rudi No exceptions. My program to select a number of batters, than A number at bat for each batter('player') and than it does the calculations above. When I select one batter it prints the average and slugg with no problems. When I select two or more it prints different numbers just repeated.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of those lines:

```
calculate[a][0] = successfulRuns / (double)atbatt;
calculate[a][1] = totalBases / (double)atbatt;
```

You cast only the denominator. But the nominator is an integer as well. You have to cast all the variables to double. Change the lines with these:

```
calculate[a][0] = (double)((double)successfulRuns / (double)atbatt);
calculate[a][1] = (double)((double)totalBases / (double)atbatt);
```

Comment: You are casting the result of integer division.

Comment: @cagirici Nope. They are all double except for the atbatt. And like I said on my question (sorry if it didn't come through like that) if I chose only one batter with 0, 4, 0 (1 homerun, two outs) for my results, the average and slugging print out okay; .333 and 1.333 just like it should.

Comment: Now there is no error but your changes are completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you are not clearing the old values with each loop iteration to your setResult method. I can't say for certain since you have not posted the code for your AtBat class, but I would take a look at that method.

Comment: And how can I go about clearing them? I just have a set and get method for each, the set being a void method with an in parameter and the get is a static with a return value of the set parameter.

Comment: You could create a new method inside of your class resetting your instance variables to 0 and calling it at the end of your loop so you can start fresh.  Have you tried it with varying inputs rather than 3 each time? What happens?

Comment: I did and I just updated the question showing the console for diferent at bats. I also tried with a method and it didn't work, maybe I used it wrong; I will give it another try using the method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. I just had to move my equation for the    if (results[a] > 0)
                successfulRuns++;
                totalBases += results[a]; outside of the inner for loop.

its working perfect now. Thanks to those who tried to assist.

```
        for(int a = 0; a < batters; a++)
    {
    atbat[a] = Validator.getInt(sc, "Enter the number of times at bat for player "
        + (a+1) + ":    ", 0, 11);
    System.out.println();

    atbatt = atbat[a];

    double[] results = new double[atbatt];

    System.out.println("0 = out, 1 = single, 2 = double, 3 = triple, 4 = home run");

        for(int i = 0; i < atbatt; i++)
        {
            results[i] = 0;

            results[i] = Validator.getInt(sc, "Results for at-bat " + i + ":    ", -1, 5);
            bat.setResult(results[i]);
        }

            if (results[a] > 0)
            successfulRuns++;
            totalBases += results[a];

        System.out.println();

    calculate[a][0] = successfulRuns / (double)atbatt;
    calculate[a][1] = totalBases / (double)atbatt;
    }

    for(int a = 0; a < batters; a++)
    {
    NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    number.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);

    message = "Batting average: " + number.format(calculate[a][0]) + "\t"
        + "Slugging percent: " + number.format(calculate[a][1]);

    System.out.println(message);
    }
```